# Hash of (Array of Tuples) causing compile/runtime error "index out of bounds for tuple {(String, String -> Void)}"

Tags: crystal-lang

I am trying to make a Hash of Arrays with tuples in them. This is causing a weird issue which I suspect is a compiler bug, but I am not 100% sure.

The syntax I am using:

```
class SomeClass
  @@weird_object = Hash(String, Array(Tuple(String, String -> ))).new {|h, k| h[k] = [] of Tuple(String, String -> ) }

  #...
  def self.some_method
    @@weird_object.each do |tuple|
      pp tuple[0]
      pp tuple[1] #=> This causes compile error "index out of bounds for tuple {(String, String -> Void)}"
    end

    @@weird_object.each do |the_sting, callback|
      #this causes a "Nil trace:" for the callback parameter
    end
#...
end
```

It looks like this has become a tuple of a `(String, String -> void)` object, and not `String, String -> void`. This error shows up when I run  `crystal spec` but not when I run `crystal build ./src/main.cr`.

Is this a compiler/runtime error, or have I messed up the syntax?

---

Crystal 0.8.0 [e363b63] (Sat Sep 19 12:00:17 UTC 2015)

Comment: Can you re-check your example? because for me, fixing the typo in the variable name in the first line, I'm not getting the compile errors you describe.

Comment: I typed wrong when renaming it here on SO. I still get the error.

Comment: I am however declaring this in class scope.. That might be the issue. Updating the question, hang on.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to reproduce (after fixing the `end` and adding `SomeClass.some_method` to the end so it actually gets typed).

Comment: I get the error during `spec`. Have you tried running your code?

Comment: Of course, else I wouldn't claim it doesn't reproduce. Neither `crystal` nor `crystal spec`  produces any error with your sample after adding the missing `end` and `SomeClass.some_method` to the end.

Comment: And you are using the same version of crystal? Weird.. I will upload a gist, or maybe the entire repo, so you can have a look at precisely what I am doing.

Comment: @JonneHaß: Have a look here. Much appreciated if you could figure out why I am getting the error I am describing above. [githubrepo](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/crystal-untangle).

Comment: Cloned the repo, ran `crystal spec`, I get a bunch of failures but no compiler error, both on latest HEAD and 0.8.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91383/discussion-between-cort3z-and-jonne-hass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual code has:

```
Hash(String, Array({String, String -> })).new
```

This tuple is the same as

```
{(String, String ->)}
```

So you need parens to disambiguate

```
Hash(String, Array({String, (String -> )})).new
```

Your actual code also has a problem with Void appearing everywhere, I'm not sure why, but a few casts can workaround it. Here's the full diff to make it work

```
diff --git a/src/untangle/aggregator.cr b/src/untangle/aggregator.cr
index 8c49681..7553eb2 100644
--- a/src/untangle/aggregator.cr
+++ b/src/untangle/aggregator.cr
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ class Aggregator
    @@subscribers_all = Array(String, String ->).new
    @@responders = Hash(String, (String ->)).new
    #@@reroutes = {} of String => Proc(String)
-   @@reroutes = Hash(String, Array({String, String -> })).new {|h, k| h[k] = Array({String, String -> }).new }
+   @@reroutes = Hash(String, Array({String, (String -> )})).new {|h, k| h[k] = Array({String, (String -> )}).new }

    def self.subscribe (message_type, &callback : String ->)
        @@subscribers[message_type] << callback
@@ -35,11 +35,11 @@ class Aggregator
            spawn do
                message_type = ch.receive
                data = ch.receive
-               callback.call(message_type, data)
+               callback.call(message_type, data as String)
            end

            ch.send(message_type)
-           ch.send(data)
+           ch.send(data as String)
        end

        @@subscribers[message_type].each do |callback|
@@ -48,14 +48,14 @@ class Aggregator
            spawn do
                callback.call(ch.receive)
            end
-           ch.send(data)
+           ch.send(data as String)
        end

        @@reroutes[message_type].each do |tuple| #|to_type, callback|
            # puts "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
            # pp tuple
            # puts "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
-           Aggregator.publish(tuple[0], tuple[1].call(data))
+           Aggregator.publish(tuple[0], tuple[1].call(data as String))
        end
    end
    def self.request(message_type, arguments)
```

Please also give http://crystal-lang.org/docs/conventions/coding_style.html a read if you plan adoption of your library in the Crystal community.

Comment: I tried both syntaxes, but yeah, it needs the parentheses in both variations. Thanks! And, yeah, the code is a mess now because I was trying out all kinds of things to resolve this particular issue.